# What should we define as a prime number, as some definitions don’t go into enough detail, and some seem over the top.

Tags: prime-numbers, definition

There are many possible definitions of a prime number such as the google search result of ‘prime number definition’:

> ’a number that is divisible only by itself and 1 (e.g. 2, 3, 5, 7, 11).’

Though by this definition, one could argue that therefore the only prime number is -1. Take 2 as an example, it is divisible by 2, 1, -1, and -2; as none of those give a fractional part. And if one argues that factors cannot be negative, that I see to say the negative numbers can’t have proper pairs of factors. -1 however I saw only divisible by 1 and -1 so it is the only integer that fits the definition.

There are several other definitions, that give our definition of prime numbers, but some seem over the top. **So my question is as follows:
Using mathematical notation, what is the fewest symbols the set of prime numbers (in the group of natural numbers bounded under addition) can be defined.**

edit - Please read the actual question before commenting it as a duplicate or giving answers that don’t actually answer my question. This is not asking for **a** definition of prime numbers, I’m asking for the **SIMPLEST POSSIBLE DEFINITION**, as in, requires the least amount of information, of the set of prime numbers.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84647/discussion-on-question-by-l-mcdonald-what-should-we-define-as-a-prime-number-a).

Comment: It all depends on what you're using the set of primes as.  If you need $\pm 1$ you simply union that in and define a new set.  If you need all negative primes you can say $x$ is prime iff $(x)$ the ideal generated by $x$ is prime (in $\Bbb{Z})$.